# How can i Share an image without saving it to Gallery in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using ShareMediaTask to share an image.I'm able to do this after saving an image to my Phone gallery but i want it directly before saving it to gallery. How can i do this ? I have done this but i dont want that photo chooser task open before sharing, i want directly it share.

```
    private void mnuShare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, null);
            bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
                mediaLibrary.SavePicture("Picture.jpg", stream);

        }
       MessageBox.Show("Picture Saved...");
        var chooser = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoChooserTask();
        chooser.Completed += chooser_Completed;
       chooser.Show();
      _fileName = e.ToString();

    }
    void ShowShareMediaTask(string path)
    {
        ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
        shareMediaTask.FilePath = path;
        shareMediaTask.Show();
    }
    void chooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        _fileName = e.OriginalFileName.ToString();
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();

            shareMediaTask.FilePath = _fileName;
            shareMediaTask.Show();

        }
```

Comment: show what you have tried till now

Comment: I have edited my question. please have a look

Comment: As far as I know you can't. In order to share it you need to have it somewhere saved. The only thing I don't know is if you could save it to your app locally. Try searching for that first.

Comment: if you don't want to use your phone gallery then you can use isolatedstorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use `ShareMediaTask` only with photos from the gallery. There is no way around it.

However, in Windows Phone 8.1 you can share any file from isolated storage, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx